# Unable to connect to the internet

Tags: vmware

When I run Ubuntu 12.04.3 on VMware Player, the following message is displayed:

```
Cannot connect the virtual device sata0:1 because no corresponding device is available on the host.
Do you want to try to connect this virtual device every time you power on the virtual machine?
YES/NO
```

Would that be the cause for the connection problem? If so, how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: sata devices are storage (HDD and alike) not wireless cards

Comment: Nope, that's a hard drive issue (sata). Are you sure the network config is setup correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix internet connection problem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/417806/how-can-i-fix-internet-connection-problem)

Answer (score 5):

It appears VMware Player cannot locate the VM's hard drive. You'll need to reattach it. If you didn't make one to begin with, you'll need to do so or remove the SATA device from the VM.

Browse for SATA hard drive:

- [Screenshot 1](http://s28.postimg.org/gql2o69jh/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_1.png)
- [Screenshot 2](http://s28.postimg.org/ryz9bynd9/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_2.png)
- [Screenshot 3](http://s28.postimg.org/fyieoz5cd/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_3.png)
- [Screenshot 4](http://s28.postimg.org/b9xtg1qrx/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_4.png)
- [Screenshot 5](http://s28.postimg.org/nfrm46uvh/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_5.png)
- [Screenshot 6](http://s28.postimg.org/4ei6aolot/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_6.png)
- [Screenshot 7](http://s28.postimg.org/msspenxzh/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_7.png)
- [Screenshot 8](http://s28.postimg.org/8owu69qrx/screenshot_askubuntu_com_vpbfshd_8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to open edit settings -> cd/rom, un-select "auto detect" and select "use vmware iso" (2nd option)

Comment: use mango's directions below....

Comment: Straight-forward, thanks. I relocated the disk image so it could not find where I moved it.